# Mirrored Wordpress Random Query on same page

Tags: wordpress

I am using a wordpress query to display 3 posts at random from a custom post type. I am using the following code which is working fine:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=my_post_type&orderby=rand&showposts=3'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

Do Stuff

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

However, I want to mirror the same query below to show the same items once again. So two wordpress queries on one page, the first query picking 3 random posts and the second query showing the exact same results of the first query. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Inside the loop you can probably save it as a $myPostVar.="Content"; and echo it later or you can even put everything inside a array to display later as well if you want to specify different content formatting.

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm clueless with this, do you know what would be the full code including the current php I am using? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out :)

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&orderby=rand&showposts=3'); ?>
<?php $i=0; ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

Do Stuff

<?php
    $myPostVar[$i] = array (
            'title'     => get_the_title(),
            'content'   => get_the_content()
    );
    $i++;
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php foreach ($myPostVar as $Postvar) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo $Postvar['title']; ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $Postvar['content']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thats Robert, thats great!